# Laravel order by custom date field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

laravel orderBy id works fine with this function:

```
News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

But I'm struggling to achieve this with a custom field.

My custom date field (sorting) is a jQuery UI datepicker field that fills a chosen date and it's in this format:

```
yy-mm-dd
```

so, if I choose from the datepicker let's say today it will be displayed as a 2017-12-05 and that saves in the database in a same format.

The reason for using this custom field is to add a old news articles, but in a different order.

I've tried to do this with:

```
News::orderBy('sorting', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

but this error is displayed:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sorting' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `news` order by `sorting` desc limit 20 offset 0)
```

That column does exists in my database.

How can I order my created articles using my custom "sorting" date field in Laravel?

EDIT:

This is the function for the news lists:

```
public function newsList() {
        $news = News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        return view('news-list', compact('news'));
    }
```

As I mention before this works, but the idea is to order by a custom date field.

Comment: Show the database schema for `news`, please

Comment: Hi, aynber, I've edited the thread.

Comment: what format is sorting? datetime or varchar? Y-m-d or d-m-Y

Comment: Can you execute the query on the database directly?

Comment: @satvision83 I don't think this is answerable without your table schema or your migration script.

Comment: That's just the function. Try `DESCRIBE news` from within the mysql console, and post the results.

Comment: The field has type "date" in MySQL. I've tried with "datetime" but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, guys I've found the problem! :)

I'll post it here, so it might be useful for someone else.

I'm using the Laravel Translatable plugin. It has two models and two database for the articles. For an example "news" and "newsTranslation".

So, when I want to use orderBy, I cannot order by fields records from the "newsTranslation". That will be only possible from the "news" table.

This error was displayed

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sorting' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `news` order by `sorting` desc limit 20 offset 0)
```

because the orderBy is trying to order the articles from the "news", not the "newsTranslation" and in my case that field wasn't available in the "news" table.

I've fix that by creating a date custom field in the "news". Now everything works fine.